# True or False: Do Two Anti-Derivatives Necessarily Differ by a Constant?

Tags: calculus

Is it true or false that if $$F'(x) = G'(x)$$ then $$F(x) = G(x) + C.$$ No more details are given (continuity, etc...)

I think this is false but I can't think of an example.

Comment: Do you want the equality to hold at every point of the domain? Or just almost everywhere?

Comment: They don't say... I just need a counter example

Comment: The example I gave in [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/171066) (based on the stuff in [this post](http://blog.wolfram.com/2008/01/19/mathematica-and-the-fundamental-theorem-of-calculus/)) might be of interest.

Comment: @J.M. that is a really good example. I am a little confused now though; the function given by the OP to that question has points of discontinuity, i.e. points where the derivative does not exist, so if we want the equality $F'(x)=G'(x)$ to hold everywhere, and not just almost everywhere, then it seems it would not be relevant (unless I am misunderstanding something). My gut feeling is that the statement might actually be true if we demand the equality holds everywhere, not just a.e., but I can't think of a proof or counterexample. Maybe something about Darboux functions?

Comment: I suppose a clarification is certainly in order, @William. You are right that the example I linked to is only "almost". (And that's part of why I did not write an answer.)

Comment: @mor: As existing comments note, the (mutual) domain of $F'$ and $G'$ is a crucial detail. If $F'(x) = G'(x)$ for all $x$ in some _interval_ $I$ of real numbers, then $F$ and $G$ differ by a constant on $I$. In general, you can have "different constants on different intervals", e.g., $\operatorname{sgn}(x) = x/|x|$ on the set of non-zero real numbers. (The function is non-constant, but its derivative exists and is identically zero throughout the set of non-zero reals.)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simpler counterexample, but it may not be the correct solution, depending on subtle details of what is wanted.

Let $f(x) $ be the absolute value function and let $g(x)$ be the function which is $|x|$ for $x\le0$ and $x+1$ for $x>0$.

Then $f$ and $g$ have identical derivatives (both of which are defined if and only if $x≠0$) but do not differ by a constant function.

I would not normally hand over a solution like this, but I judge that it will be just as instructive, in this case, to decide whether the example is a valid answer to the question.

Answer (score 1):

This is too long for a comment, and is not a valid counterexample if we want the equality $$F'(x)=G'(x)$$ to hold *everywhere* and not just almost everywhere (i.e. everywhere except a set of measure zero).

With those caveats in mind, consider the [Cantor function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function):

[image]

[image]

[image]

(The definition is related to the Cantor set, although long enough that I don't care to post it again here.)

Except for a set of measure zero, the derivative of the Cantor function is zero, the same as any constant function. However, the Cantor function is clearly *not* constant, hence if we allow the derivative to be undefined except on a set of measure zero, then this is a valid counterexample.